# After downgrade magento 2.3.5-p1 to magento 2.3.4 getting error

Tags: error, magento2.3.5, downgrade

**After downgrade magento 2.3.5-p1 to magento 2.3.4 getting error when setup upgrade command fire**

```
An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkappdeploymentconfig(alias: Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig).
```

Comment: There should be more informations in the Exception.log, can you post these as well. On another node: Magento isn't really build to downgrade. A lot of problems can occure.

Comment: not getting any error in Exception.log,

Comment: Hmm then try to debug it in vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php in the method createFromAbstractFactory.

Comment: I am also getting this error after upgrading from magento v 2.2.6 to 2.3.5-p1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that Magento doesn't support to downgrade. However, if you still want to do it, you need to install Magento version 2.3.4, create a fresh site then migrate data from your old store to the new one.